# How to prevent Bluetooth mouse/keyboard from going Paired

Tags: bluetooth

I have a wireless keyboard and mouse and If i leave it alone form 3 mins, it goes from connected to paired. How do I prevent my keyboard and mouse from going Idle. It always lags when I try to use it once the status has switched to "Paired" from "Connected"

Comment: Battery-powered peripherals will of course enter power-saving mode very soon. Otherwise, the batteries would be drained in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the receiver, it is possible there is some interference from device to bluetooth receiver.

Attempt plugging into a different USB port as well.